# SQLite "<>" operator not working

Tags: sqlite

I have this query:

```
SELECT username FROM users INNER JOIN friends WHERE friends.user_a = users.id OR friends.user_b = users.id AND users.username <> 'david';
```

It is returning a row where users.username = 'david'.  How can I have this not returned?

'users' table structure/sample data
[image]

'friends' table structure/sample data
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try `NOT LIKE '%david%'` for any non-print chars?

try `WHERE (friends.user_a = users.id OR friends.user_b = users.id) AND users.username <> 'david';`

**Explanation:**
Your logic was `friends.user_a = users.id OR friends.user_b = users.id AND users.username <> 'david'`
You were saying: "bring me anyone who's friend with user_a OR etc..."
so when the first applies it doesn't need to check the rest, but after the parentheses, we are saying: "Bring me anyone who 1. Is friends with user_a or users_b 2. His user_name is not 'david'".

Comment: that did it, thanks.  Will mark as answer.  For a new person, why do I need the parenthesis?  Would like to actually learn the reason behind that instead of just copy and pasting.  Appreciate the help.